# Bind event for runtime added usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I need to load a usercontrol at runtime. This code works perfectly:

```
        Control ctrl = this.LoadControl("~/controls/widgets/" + widgetControlName);
        Type controlType = ctrl.GetType();
        PropertyInfo pMode = controlType.GetProperty("Mode");
        PropertyInfo pFlyerWidgetId = controlType.GetProperty("FlyerWidgetId");

        pFlyerWidgetId.SetValue(ctrl, flyerWidgetId, null);
        pMode.SetValue(ctrl, "EDIT", null);

        plhContent.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

On that .ascx file I have a "SaveData" method binded to a simply button but I cannot handle it as when I click nothing happens. I'm wondering how to fire events from a runtime loaded usercontrol. Any hints?

PS: The placeholder "plhContent" is inside an updatepanel

Comment: show the rendered html for the button. check `onclick` in html

Comment: Try setting update panel's `UpdateMode=Always` if you already set some async trigger and `conditional` mode

Comment: I did it but nothing happens. Strange, I checked the html but there are not onclick event binded to the button